# Create Trigger does not replicate in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, replication

We created a trigger in the master database but the trigger does not show up in the slave database.

Here is an example of the create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER filter_pos_transaction_delivery_combo_details BEFORE INSERT ON `pos-transaction_delivery_combo_details`
for each row
begin
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(200);
    SET @store_code = (SELECT value FROM `admin-settings` WHERE attribute = 'local_store_code' LIMIT 1);

    if STRCMP(new.store_code,@store_code) != 0 then
        if STRCMP( @store_code,'MAINDB') != 0 then
            set msg = "SKIPPING INSERTION: THIS DATA IS NOT FOR THIS LOCAL DB - pos-transaction_delivery_combo_details ";
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

Here is the cnf configuration:

```
[mysqld]
user                        = mysql
port                        = 3306
datadir                     = /data/mysql/
pid-file                    = /data/mysql/fusion-maindb.pid
socket                      = /data/mysql/fusion-maindb.sock
log_error                   = /datalog/mysql_error_log/mysql_error.log

## Replication and Logging Settings ###
server_id                   = 11111111
log_bin                     = /datalog/rep_binlogs/maindb-bin.log
binlog_do_db                = fusion
replicate_do_db             = fusion
max_binlog_size             = 1000M
slave-skip-errors           = 1644,1007,1062,1449,1146,1062
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 8000M
log_slave_updates           = 1
skip-external-locking
sync_binlog                 = 1
slave_net_timeout           = 60
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    = 120
binlog_format               = STATEMENT
slave_compressed_protocol   = 1
wait_timeout                = 300
interactive_timeout         = 300
```

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Comment: share your mysql version and your config file my.cnf or my.ini and exact how you execute your trigger creation statement on master.

Comment: We are using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your binlog format:

When using **statement-based replication**, triggers on the slave are executed by statements that are executed on the master (and replicated to the slave).

When using **row-based replication**, triggers are not executed on the slave due to statements that were run on the master and then replicated to the slave. Instead, when using row-based replication, the changes caused by executing the trigger on the master are applied on the slave.

Comment: But the trigger doesn't show up on slave. The triggers are only created in the master database.

Comment: Yes it means you are using mixed based replication...
in this case command created by triggers on master is replicated to the slave not the trigger itself..

So your data is up do date, no worries in that..

triggers are not running in slave, only changes done by trigger on master is replicated..

Comment: But what if we need the triggers in our slave databases, do we need to manually create the triggers in the slave databases?

Comment: yes you need to create manually but this will lead to data inconsistency..
because the master server replicate the command created by trigger at master to slave and slave trigger again execute the command..

Comment: what if we are using the triggers to confirm if the data should replicate to slave base on a table from the slave?

Comment: you can create a test table and trigger on master and check the results on slave server..

Comment: We have a table in our slave database that are the basis of the triggers in the slave to filter the data that goes to the slave database from master database.

Comment: yes then you can add new table and do whatever you want in new table with triggers..
if you enter data in existing table via trigger then it will be inconsistent.

Comment: @AmanAggarwal you are very much incorrect.  The trigger definition should *always* replicate to the slave.  The slave does not *fire* the trigger when a binlog event in `ROW` format is received, but the definition needs to be there.